# How to add year and end of month in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, dateadd

Mabuhay!

Is there any shortcode for updating date with additional 2 years and end of month?

Sample:
Account Opened: 2017-04-04

Expiry: 2019-04-30

```
UPDATE dbname SET [Expiry] = DateAdd(year,2,[AccountOpened])
```

Without adding this `UPDATE dbname SET [Expiry] = DateAdd(mm,1,[AccountOpened])`

because it will add 1 month instead of last month date.

Thanks

Comment: If you are talking about SQL Server it now has a [EOMONTH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/eomonth-transact-sql) function. In your case you can use it with the second parameter 24: `EOMONTH(AccountOpened, 24)`

Comment: Please tag your DBMS. Is it MySQL? PostgreSQL? SQL Server? ... You should always tag your DBMS with SQL questions to get approopriate answers.

Comment: Thanks for reminding, yes its for sql server sorry for confusion. Noted on this one.

Answer (score 1):

If your are using SQLSERVER following script will give desire result. Before performing UPDATE operation take back of Original data.

```
UPDATE dbname 
SET [Expiry] = DATEADD(d,-1,DATEADD(m,DATEDIFF(m,0, (DATEADD(YY,2,AccountOpened))) + 1,0))
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for Sql Server (any version, I think)

```
UPDATE dbName
SET [Expiry] = DATEADD(MONTH, ((YEAR([AccountOpened]) - 1898) * 12) + MONTH([AccountOpened]), -1)
```

[I made a fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/03b3a/1)

For Sql Server 2012+ you can simply:

```
UPDATE dbName SET [Expiry] = EOMONTH([AccountOpened], 24)
```

For MySql (which I guess you are not using because you are using brackets for your fields, but here it is nonetheless):

```
UPDATE dbName SET Expiry = LAST_DAY(DATE_ADD(AccountOpened, INTERVAL 2 YEAR))
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this query?

Where Clause = CAST([CustomDate2] AS DATE) between CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE) and DATEADD(day, *+/-number here*,CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE))

```
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,"your date")+1,0))
```

LastDay_AnyMonth
ResultSet:
LastDay_AnyMonth
———————–

> 2007-08-31 23:59:59.000